# I want to save the retrieved file on my Database on custom Path like opening a savefiledialog

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
MySqlConnection.Open()
            command.Connection = MySqlConnection
            command.CommandText = "select File_Name,File from add_document where Document_ID = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"

            READER = command.ExecuteReader
            READER.Read()

                Dim filebytes() As Byte = CType(READER(1), Byte())
                Dim FStream As New FileStream(READER(0).ToString, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write)
                FStream.Write(filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length)
                FStream.Close()

                MessageBox.Show("File Retrieved")
                READER.Close()
                MySqlConnection.Close()
            End If
```

Here is my code, when I retrieved a file on my database I wanted to choose where I want to save it(what folder etc.) Any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: If you want to save to a user defined path, then get the path destination from the user before that code, then use it.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] - you didnt actually ask a question or tell us what part you are having trouble with

Comment: how can I do that please ? I'm sorry I'm new to this kind of problem.